# MYSQL driver class not found

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

Please i'm trying to have a DB data from a jsp file, but the driver class is not found (output error), it works good when i'm executing the java class directly but it's not found when i'm calling it from the jsp file.

Here is the jsp code

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.Class"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="DAO.*"%>

<%
 try{
   List<String> names=DB.getNames();
   out.print(names);
   out.flush();
    }
 catch(Exception e)
    {
   e.printStackTrace();
    }
   %>
```

And basically the same in the java class when executing the main .

```
public static void main(String[] args){
for(Iterator it=DB.getNames().iterator(); it.hasNext();) 
    System.out.println(it.next()); 

 }
```

Works good from java directly but not found when called from jsp.

The error shows the problem in the db connection function an especialy in this line `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at DAO.DB.connect(DB.java:21)
at DAO.DB.getNames(DB.java:35)
```

Comment: It basically saying that the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` cannot be found the in the classpath. Unzip your war and look inside WEB-INF/lib/ folder to see if mysql..jar has been included.

Comment: Yes actually is wasn't in the web-inf but i solved it using the solution sugested, by adding the jat to "CATALINA_HOME/lib", thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is being faced because, your Tomcat is unable to find this class that is being referenced in your `JSP` / `Java` code.

You need to place your `MySQL Connector/J` jar in your `CATALINA_HOME/lib` folder or in `<yourApplicationWAR>/WEB-INF/lib`, hoping that your DB related code is in the `JSP` itself. Latter is preferred over placing your Connector/J in your Tomcat (or any such similar app-server)

If the code is in your JAVA class, then you would need to put it in your IDE classpath & preferably into your CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks it works, i added the jar into "CATALINA_HOME/lib" and the problem is solved, many thanks

Comment: Happy to help @Mouad